# About Custom Fields of Moodle

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I am using Moodle 3.11.

I have a custom course field named discount.

how can i fetch names of all the course that provides discount on a new page?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this query for Moodle - replace `d.value` with the required field

```
$sql = 'SELECT c.id AS courseid, c.fullname AS coursename, d.value AS discount
    FROM mdl_customfield_category cat
    JOIN mdl_customfield_field f ON f.categoryid = cat.id AND f.shortname = :shortname
    JOIN mdl_customfield_data d ON d.fieldid = f.id
    JOIN mdl_course c ON c.id = d.instanceid
    WHERE cat.area = :area'

$courses = $DB->get_records_sql($sql, array('area' => 'course' 'shortname' => 'discount'));

for each ($courses as $course) {
    // Display $course->fullame and $course->discount
}
```

Or this for Totara

```
$sql = 'SELECT c.id AS courseid, c.fullname, d.data AS discount
        FROM {course_info_field} f
        JOIN {course_info_data} d ON d.fieldid = f.id AND d.data > ''
        JOIN {course} c ON c.id = d.courseid
        WHERE f.shortname = :shortname'

$courses = $DB->get_records_sql($sql, array('shortname' => 'discount'));

for each ($courses as $course) {
    // Display $course->fullame and $course->discount
}
```

Comment: There is no such tables as course_info_field and course_info_data in database.

Comment: Oops, that's Totara not Moodle - how did you create a course custom field in Moodle?

Comment: in site adminstration there is option inside cousre named manage custom fields

Comment: In your question "I have a custom course field named discount." - how did you create the discount field?

Comment: in site admintration inside course tab there is custom field setting given from there i created it

Comment: I've updated the answer for Moodle